# How to get indicies of numpy array that equal any values of another array?

Tags: python, numpy, slice, indices

I have a numpy array `A`, of say length 100, and another array `B`, of length 4.

I want to get a mask of also length 100, and this mask will have values of TRUE, when the element of `A` equals ANY of the elements of `B`, and FALSE otherwise. How can I do that in an efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
a = np.random.rand(100)
b = np.random.rand(4)
print([(element in b) for element in a])
print('\n')
print([(element in a) for element in b])
```

I think that's what you want

Comment: Thanks, although I would rather do it without a for-loop. Apparently this works `np.in1d'